# Symfony2 Configuration rootNode not recognised

Tags: symfony, configuration, bundle, config

I am trying to define the configuration parameters available to users of my bundle and I'm having a problem getting the root node to be recognised.

I have created a `Configuration` class with a `getConfigTreeBuilder` that looks like this:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('rally_stats');

    // Here you should define the parameters that are allowed to
    // configure your bundle. See the documentation linked above for
    // more information on that topic.

    $rootNode->children()->arrayNode('projects')
        ->prototype('scalar')->end();

    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

Using that, I would expect to be able to create a section in `config.yml` that looks like this:

```
rally_stats:
    projects:
        - project1
        - project2
```

and then to be able to access the config with:

```
$this->getContainer()->getParameter('rally_stats.projects');
```

However, when trying to load that config I get this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "rally_stats" 
(in /Users/stu/Projects/rally-stats/app/config/config.yml). Looked for namespace "rally_stats", found "framework", "security", "
twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", 
"wa_ndisco_rally_stats", "jms_di_extra", "jms_aop", "debug", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution" 
in /Users/stu/Projects/rally-stats/app/config/config.yml 
(which is being imported from "/Users/stu/Projects/rally-stats/app/config/config_dev.yml").
```

The closest is `wa_ndisco_rally_stats`, which was the original root name when the bundle was generated by Symfony. I've grepped for that & just `wa_ndisco` and there are no other references to either.

If I remove the config section & dump-reference for my bundle, I get this:

```
# Default configuration for "WANdiscoRallyStatsBundle"
rally_stats:
    projects:             []
```

Why can I not add config using the node name I've provided?

If I do give it the name it thinks it should have `wa_ndisco_rally_stats`, I can't access it either, I get the same error for that name too.

Comment: Have you deleted your cache?  Are you sure you are editing the correct bundle file?  You do have a RallyStatsBundle and not a WaNDiscoRallyStats bundle?

Comment: Yes, cache cleared (manually, cache:clear fails with the same error), I am editing the Configuration class in `WANdisco\RallyStatsBundle\DependencyInjection` namespace, and you can see the bundle name fro that ...

Comment: Does your DI extension class override getAlias()?

Comment: No, just `load()`

Thanks for your suggestions ...

Comment: I've decided it's more hassle than it's worth just to get a different name in the config, once you override getAlias() you need to start on other methods too. I'll just stick with the default name. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should not have to change getAlias.  Just seems that somewhere you have a disco hanging around.  Stuck in the seventies I guess.  Is your app on a public git repository?  Be glad to take a look at it.  Bit of a mystery.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your configuration is wrong:

```
$rootNode->children()->arrayNode('projects')
    ->prototype('scalar')->end();
```

Should be:

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('projects')
            ->prototype('scalar')->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
```

and if you want to acces it from parameters you have to go to your bundle extension class and set it like this for example:

```
    $container->setParameter('rally_stats.projects', $config['projects']);
```

[Here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#normalization) you can read something about it.

Comment: Am I missing something, or is that last part about calling `setParameter()` not mentioned in the docs?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html here is something about parameters, should be enough

Comment: I know how to get & set parameters, my point was more that the docs on creating friendly config for bundles doesn't mention that you have to set it after you're normalised it.